# How to more secure OAuth2 Request?

Tags: api, security, encryption, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to secure my API service by using OAuth2. In below scheme, phone request to OAuth server and I'm using SSL pinning between my API Server and client  but I'm not sure If It can be exposed via main in the middle attack;

1-) An attacker can get OAuth url with MIMA and for example attack DDOS?

2-) Can attacker reach keychain on iOS and get JWT?

3-) Can attacker get certificate with MIMA or reverse enginner? So that SSL pinning become non-secure?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: SSL pinning mitigates the risk of receiving an MITM attack. But you are not using oauth2 and oauth2 it is not related with MITM or SSL pining, so try to clarify your question.

Comment: I changed my question. Can you please check it? @pedrofb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to secure my API service by using OAuth2.

First of all, **your scheme is not accoding with OAuth2 flow**. See [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

The API server should play two roles (theoretically, not necessarily two servers)

- **Authorization server**: Authenticates the client and issues an access token
- **Resource server**: Protected resources which requires to present a valid access token

The app **does not ask to user for username/password directly**. The request is made by the Authorization Server using web redirections, so user's credentials are never requested by the client apps.

> 1-) An attacker can get OAuth url with MIMA and for example attack DDOS?**

Oauth2 URL can be public. This is not a problem

> 2-) Can attacker reach keychain on iOS and get JWT?

No, it is protected by Operating System

> 3-) Can attacker get certificate with MIMA or reverse engineer? So that SSL pinning become non-secure?

The pinning certificate is public and usually are published by the Certificate Authority. It is a reduced set of CA's root certificates that are accepted by the client when establishing an SSL connection. An attacker can not present a valid certificate of this CA because he does not own the private key, so he can not perform a MITM attack.

---

Disclaimer: Oauth2 was designed mainly for web applications. If you use native applications I suggest using OpenIdConnect, which is an extension of OAuth2, to avoid the intensive usage or web redirections

Comment: But I will be using this system for my apps log-in page so not for 3rd party app. How can I not ask username or password directly? Can you please explain with more detail :) I'm thinking about getting username + password and encode it with a secret key and decode it in Oauth2 server. @pedrofb

Comment: I think I don't need to use OAuth2? Just JWT looks enough in my situation?

Comment: oauth2 is suitable if you are providing a service / API to a third party, or want to centralize the authentication of your applications according to a standard. It seems that this is not your case, so a simpler solution may be more appropriate

Comment: Is It acceptable that I send encrypted username + password via secret key and decrypt it on server and return JWT If It is true then check JWT on client side?

Comment: The security level of sending the password encrypted or clear is the same because if a MITM attacker captures it, he can authenticate. But you said that you are using SSL pinning, so the channel is encrypted and protected against MITM, so you do not need additional encryption